# Widget launches Dialog on click

Tags: android

Is it possible to launch a dialog on widget click or do I have to launch a Activity on widget click then a dialog?

Answer (score 11):

I am sure you have already solved that, but I'll write here anyway, in case other like me land on this answer.

To launch a Dialog by clicking a Widget you can define an activity that is styled like a dialog and launch it when the widget gets clicked.

First of all add the activity in the manifest, let's call it `DialogWidgetActivity`

```
<activity
    android:name=".DialogWidgetActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    ...
/>
```

Then in your WidgetProvider, let's call it `MyWidgetProvider` bind the click of the widget with the launch of the activity

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent to launch the activity-dialog
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DialogWidgetActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to it
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_container, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
        // widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}
}
```

Note that here we have bind the launch of the activity to the click on the widget_container element of the dialog. You can easily achieve this by assigning the id widget_container, `android:id="@+id/widget_container"`, to the root element of the widget layout.

You can then write your activity-dialog and its layout like you would do for a normal full screen activity.

My sources were [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862756/how-to-show-a-dialog-on-a-widget) and [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Hope I helped :)

Answer (score -2):

You can launch `AlertDialog`on click of a widget.

**Update:**

Add the following code for onclick listener.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Message");
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: I'm attempting, but failing, do you have code, or a link to an example? Thanks.  I've been messing around with pending intents set in the `onUpdate` method of the `AppWidgetProvider`, I've got the basic `AlertDialog` ready to go should my clicks have some sort of effect.

Comment: Please Check updated answer. You can modify per your requirements.

Comment: `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`. So nope. Voted down.